# quadratic programming /symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, quadratic-programming

I have a quadratic program with $ F: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, F(x)=x^TQx$ I want to find a symmetric matrix M for Q, such that $F(x)=x^TMx$ holds for all x.
I can write Q as sum of symmetric matrices and antisymmetric matrices:
$ Q = \frac{1}{2}(Q + Q^T) +\frac{1}{2} (Q-Q^T)$
Is this the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Moreover, the antisymmetric matrix does not contribute. After all, $x^T Q x$ is a scalar and therefore $x^T Q x = (x^T Q x)^T = x^T Q^T x$ for any $x$. Consequently $x^T(Q-Q^T)x=0$.

So we can write:
$$M=\frac 12(Q+Q^T)$$

Comment: Very nice:) In the end I can write $Q=\frac{1}{2} (Q + Q^T)$. Thank you very much:)

Comment: Just saying @SvenMath, that equation is only true if $Q$ was symmetric to begin with, but it doesn't have to be. It's just that both the left hand side and the right hand side define the same $F$, but the original $Q$ does not have to be symmetric.

Comment: You mean,if I consider only Q. If you consider F with Q, then it hasn't to be symmetric. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes @SvenMath. In $F$ the matrix $Q$ does not have to symmetric, in which case $Q\ne \frac 12(Q+Q^T)$. We can write $F(x)=x^T M x$ though with $M= \frac 12(Q+Q^T)$, which is the same function $F$.

Comment: Thank you very much:) Now i unterstand the difference, you pointed out. Thank you:)